# Create a new password in django

Tags: python, django, change-password

I had password change form like below

**forms.py**

```
class PasswordChangeForm(forms.Form):
    old_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    new_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['new_password'] != self.cleaned_data['confirm_password']:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('The new passwords must be same'))
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data
```

**template.html**

```
<form action="/save/data/" method="post">
   <div>
      <p>{{form.old_password}}</p>
      <span>{{form.old_password.errors}}</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <p>{{form.new_password}}</p>
      <span>{{form.new_password.errors}}</span>
   </div>
   <div>
       <p>{{form.confirm_password}}</p>
      <span>{{form.confirm_password.errors}}</span>
   </div>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required 
def change_password(request):
    user_obj = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    form = PasswordChangeForm()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = PasswordChangeForm(reques.POST)
        #########
        Here in this part i need to check if the user given old passoword
        matched the already saved password in the database, create a password
        with the user given new password
        #########
        new_password = form.cleaned_data['new_password']
        ......
        user_obj.password = new_password 
        ..........
    return render_to_response('template.html',{'form':form})
```

So in the above code, how can we check the password saved in the database with the old password given by the user ?, Also how can we create the new password and sve in to the database ?

After that send an email to user, that ur password has been changed successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the user object. So you can just call it's `set_password` method.

```
request.user.set_password(password)
```

Also, you don't need to get the user again from the database. You're making an unnecessary DB request. `request.user` is the user.

I would rewrite the entire view like so,

```
from django.shortcuts import render

@login_required 
def change_password(request):
form = PasswordChangeForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid()
    if request.user.check_password(form.cleaned_data['old_password']):
        request.user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['new_password'])
        request.user.save()
        return render(request, 'success.html')
return render(request, 'template.html', {'form':form})
```

This means that if there is POST data you initialise the form with it. Otherwise it gets `None`. If the form is valid (which an empty form never will be) then you do the password change and send them to a success page. Otherwise you return the empty form (or the form with the validation errors) to the user.

Comment: how to check if the user given old password matches the password in database ?

Comment: Your view is decorated with `login_required`, but you just use the `check_password` method

Comment: You cant check whether the new password matches the old one because they are encrypted by default with a salted hash...

Comment: Yes you can, you just use check password. The salt is stored in the database along with the hash. Salted hashes are used to prevent rainbow table attacks on leaked data. Not to prevent whether a given password matches the hash + salt stored in the database.

Comment: You shouldn't get `request.POST or None`, if you get `None`, the next line will fail: `form.is_valid()`.

Comment: No, if you get `None` the next line will be fine. The form will be invalid. As you would expect for an empty form. What do you think happens when you call `Form(None)`. Maybe you should try experimenting .

Answer (score 0):

you can check via check_password method.

```
if request.user.check_password(form.cleaned_data['old_password']):
    request.user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['new_password'])
    request.user.save()
```